# Printing prime factors of numbers in C

Tags: c

The code fits the first number and prints it constantly. how can i fix this?

```c
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    for (count = 2; i > 1; count++) {
        while (i % count == 0) {
            printf("%d ", count);
            i = i / count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the `count` loop is counting in the wrong direction.

Comment: A piece of paper and a pencil are most helpful here. Simulate your code on paper and you'll quickly find out what's wrong.

Comment: This `for(count = 2; i > 1; count++)` loop is not proper. Check it.

Comment: Why is that not proper, @Avinash?

Comment: As a general rule: you should never modify the iteration variable. This should also answer your question, though I haven't tried it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, because looking at the code `i > 1` is always True. So the for loop will run infinitely.

Comment: Consider using this as an excuse to learn to use a debugger.  That is a skill that will serve you well as long as you you regularly write code.  Or if you don't want to do that right now, then good old print statement debugging is a tried and true method: insert code at appropriate places that prints out the values of relevant variables, so that you can get a handle on what is going wrong, and some idea of where.

Comment: Look again, @Avinash: `i` is not always greater than 1 in that loop.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I run the code and the value of `i` is `2` in each iteration. https://onlinegdb.com/O5H28HiYy

Comment: The inner loop always reduces `i` to 1 so the next iteration of the outer loop goes to 2 over and over and over. You need to make a copy of `i` and factorize that copy instead of `i`. If you do that the inner loop will work even if it is a bit unconventional. I would go with `int t = i; for (int count = 2; count <= t; ++count)`

Comment: @Avinash, the value of `i` is reduced to 1 in the body of the loop.

Comment: Using more meaningful variable names might reduce confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in each iteration are as follows.

1. `count = 0; i = 0;` Doesn't enter the second **for**.
2. `count = 0; i = 1;` Doesn't enter the second **for**.
3. `count = 0; i = 2;` Enters the second **for**. `count = 2;`
4. `2 % 2 == 0` - Enters the **while**.
5. `i = 2 / 2;` `1 % 2 == 1;` Doesn't enter the **while**.
6. Back to the second **for** - `count = 3;`, `i = 1;` Doesn't enter the second **for**.
7. Back to the first **for** - `i < 20;`, so `i = 2`.
8. `count = 2; i = 2;` and we are back to step 4, with an infinite loop.

This might be what you are looking for -

```
int j, count = 0;
for (int i = 20; i > 0; i--)
{
    printf("\n%d: ", i);
    for(count = 2, j = i; j > 1; count++)
    {  
        while(j % count == 0)
        {
            printf("%d ", count);
            j = j / count;
        }  
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function that checks whether a given number `n` is prime:

```
bool is_prime(int n)
{
    if (n < 2) return false;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n/i; ++i) // Doing i*i<=n may overflow
        if (n % i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

And then call it like:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    if(is_prime(i))
        printf("%d\n", i);
```

Or more directly (i.e. without a function):

```
int main(void)
{
    int mark;
    for (int n = 2; n <= 20; n++) {
        mark = 1;
        
        for (int i = 2; i*i <= n; ++i)
            if (n % i == 0) mark = 0;
        
        if (mark) printf("%d\n", n);
    }
}
```